# How can we pull and store a referral company ID value from a branch.io link and app install by user?

Tags: branch.io

We are trying to implement a referral ID to track and store a unique referral id passed in a branch.io url but cant figure out how to handle or which branch.io api allows for this.

Use case is as follows:

1. Company within our platform shares their unique URl which contains their ID
2. Many users click on their url and then download our app in Play or Apple stores
3. When these users install the app and sign up we need to obtain and store this company ID value
4. We need access to this unique ID instantly upon app signup so we can correctly display some custom content to user.

Reviewing branch.io apis

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.